# Spring MVC. Controller and JSP collaboration

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have jsp page which contains tab control. Each tab has category name as a caption and contains a table with information about groups of selected category. Clicking on the tab should make a query in the DB and populate the table in the tab with a list of category groups. So I have a method in controller

```
public List<Group> getGroups(int idCategory) {
    return groupService.getList(idCategory);
}
```

How can I call this method in jsp?
The only way I see is to put a Map in the ModelMap where a key is a category Id and a value is a list of Groups. But I don't like this idea because we need to make all queries to fill the map, but we may not need some of them if we don't click all the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to load all the data in the controller when you render the page, then you should probably load only the data for the tab which will be displayed initially and retrieve the data for the rest of the tabs with AJAX calls as needed.

For this you would have to have some client side logic in JavaScript and probably some dedicated controller on the backend which will return the groups for given category ID for example in JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is with the model. If you want to use it that way you should make a call using ajax and then manipulating the data with javascript or a plugin for tables(DataTables for example).